# Ubuntu 20.04 install hung at "Detecting Filesystems"

Tags: system-installation

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop in a dual boot with Windows but for some reason it has been hung on "Detecting Filesystems..." for 2+ hours, I have a ~200GB EXT4 partition for Ubuntu (no swap)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue, I restarted the installation and allocated a swapspace, I guess it was a RAM issue